# For a given graph, is it a valid topological sort?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, sorting

Given a graph:

[image]

Is **'a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'f'** a valid topological sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right. For all uv edge, vertex u appears before vertex v in your list. And that's the condition that a topological sort has to fulfill.